# Como retornar uma coluna transformada em string à uma float, int?

Tags: python, tabela-html, ascii

Tive de transformar uma coluna de uma base de dados em string para poder remover os últimos dígitos dos valores, que estavam com 0.1, 0.2 ou 0.3 e isso atrapalharia meus dados futuramente. No entanto, ao tentar unir essa coluna novamente à base de dados anterior, toda a base se tornou algo que não consigo sequer ler como tabela.

Como conseguiria fazer essa coluna se tornar o que era antes, mas sem tais números 0.1,... no final?

Segue uma parte do código:

```
raiosplanetas=ascii.read('raios planetarios.txt', guess=False)

Nome_Simbad=str(raiosplanetas['SimbadName']).replace('.01' or '.02' or '0.3' or '0.4','')

raiosplanetas['Nome']=Nome_Simbad
```

A primeira linha mostra como transformei a coluna em string e retirei os valores que não queria, e a segunda é a tentativa de reintroduzi-la na tabela original.

Um exemplo do que é alterado com essa função replace:KOI-0001.01 vira KOI-0001 e KOI-5877.03 vira KOI-5877

Comment: Nome_Simbad é um número ou uma string?

Comment: Só com esse pedaço de código é complicado. Coloca o código completo pra gente te ajudar

Comment: E outra coisa. Você pode remover os números decimais sem precisar passar para uma string.

Comment: Felipe: Nome_Simbad aparentemente virou uma string quando fiz essa transformação na segunda linha do código.
Max: Eu poderia adereçar a tabela completa com a coluna 'SimbadName', mas em teoria essa parte do código é a total do problema. 
A outra maneira de remover os números seria como o Ruben sugeriu abaixo? Estou tentando ela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo simples, atravês de fazer uma troca, replace, 
Pode, dependendo do problema, remover depois do ponto

```
primeira_lista = ['KOI-0001.01','KOI-5877.03']
segunda_lista = []

for pl in primeira_lista:
  segunda_lista.append(pl[0:pl.find('.')])

print(segunda_lista)
```

saida

```
['KOI-0001', 'KOI-5877']
```

agora se deseja manter na mesma lista

```
primeira_lista = ['KOI-0001.01','KOI-5877.03']

for i in range(0,len(primeira_lista)):
  primeira_lista[i] = primeira_lista[i][0:primeira_lista[i].find('.')]

print(primeira_lista)
```

Comment: Os elementos de uma coluna se encaixam como lista? E o que eu colocaria no lugar de 'pl', para procurar na lista?

Comment: Deu certo, as respostas pras minhas duas perguntas: Sim, e deixe pl mesmo.
Muitíssimo obrigado!